# Facebook: Posting to Multiple Friend's Walls Using Multiple Friend Selector and JS SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have tried putting together some code based on some other SO questions and various web tutorials.

The error I am getting is right at the end when I try and post to my friend's walls.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<p><input type="button" onclick="sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector(); return false;" value="Recommend friends for another chance to win!" /></p>

<div id="response"></div>

<script>
FB.init({
    appId  : 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    status : true,
    cookie : true,
    oauth: true
});

function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'My Great Request'
    }, requestCallback);
}

function requestCallback(response) {
    // Handle callback here
    if (response.request && response.to) {
        var request_ids = [];
        for(i=0; i<response.to.length; i++) {
            var temp = response.request + '_' + response.to[i];
            var friend_id = response.to[i];
            request_ids.push(temp);

            //send message in here
            var opts = {
                message : 'Message',
                name : 'Name',
                link : 'http://www.facebook.com/pages/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                description : 'Description here',
                picture : 'http://www.example.com/img/some.jpg'
            };

            FB.api('/'+friend_id+'/feed', 'post', opts, function(response) {
                if (!response || response.error) {
                    // This is the error I am getting:
                    alert('Error occured');
                } else {
                    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                }
            });
            // end send message 
        }
        var requests = request_ids.join(',');       
    } else {
        alert('Didn't send recommendation to friends');
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is actually working great, it worked as soon as I granted myself the access token in graph api explorer.

Just need to set up my auth dialogue now, lots of fun!

Just thought I'd better answer this incase anyone else runs into the same situation.

Comment: go to developers.facebook.com/apps and pick an app from your list, then click 'edit app' and 'Use Graph API Explorer' will be on the left hand sidebar.